# Book about a society that used runes to harness elemental magic, which they learned about in schools

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult, magic

I have not even come close to finding this book. I read (some) of this book around 7 years ago or so. It was on the Apple Books app (orange application for iOS) though I doubt it’s still on there as I’ve searched for it.

This is what I remember. It was about a society that used elemental magic. They learned about it in schools, and some used runes to harness the magic and get better at using it. Magic was definitely normal for this society.

The main character was male, (book was filled with young adults including main character and side characters) and I specifically remember him having a crush on a girl that went to his school, and her name was Marie. She was on the cheer squad. I believe the main character ended up going to an arena to duel with magic against others, like a competition.

The cover of the book was mostly dark colors and had the main character on it, possibly wearing a hood and/or having some sort of magic displayed in his hand.

I know this is a long shot, but I’m really hoping someone can help me out despite how little detail I remember. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Could this be ***[The Buried Symbol](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/43735667-the-buried-symbol)*** (2016) by Jeffrey L. Kohanek, the first book in the *[Runes of Issalia](https://www.goodreads.com/series/182480-the-runes-of-issalia)* series...?

From Goodreads:

> Buried away for centuries, a forgotten magic lurks...waiting to return
>
> They tell Unchosen, "Accept your fate and you'll be rewarded in the next life."
>
> The threat of execution is their recourse.
>
> Rejecting his role as an outcast, Brock risks his life and obtains a false rune, marking him a member of the Empire's ruling class. Under a veil of deception and backed by natural talent, he then schemes his way into a school where the Empire's future leaders are trained.
>
> Can he maintain this charade?
>
> Within **an academy of magic, science, and combat,** he discovers secrets kept from society, among which is a forbidden magic he is able to wield.
>
> While he is determined to tame his frightening new abilities, one misstep could destroy him.

[This reader review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/3168670787?book_show_action=true&from_review_page=1) mentions a wizard school, a romance, a duel competition, and a magic system built around runes.

> The Buried Symbol is a “Wizard School” novel. It spends a great number of pages detailing the friends’ various classes, along with some entertaining segues about a mysterious prophecy, some detailed history and lore, and of course some tame, but believable romance. There are also some awesome fight scenes and **a duel competition** that is cinematic and well choreographed. **The magic system, built around runes,** order and chaos, is well thought out, and beautifully rendered on the page.

I can't find any mention of a 'Marie' within the book, but it seems have most of the other things you mentioned, and a similar cover to the one you described.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately The Buried Symbol is not the book I’m looking for. If I may go into more detail about the cover, I believe that the character is closer up and there is nothing else except for him. Thanks for trying though. I don’t think the book I’m trying to find was very popular or had a very good rating (though I’m not 100% sure)

Answer (score 2):

This is a long shot because it doesn't fully match your description, but how about [Nature Mage](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13582887-nature-mage) by Duncan Pile.

[image: Nature Mage]

> Gaspi is an ordinary boy, living in the mountain village of Aemon's Reach, but life, for Gaspi, is forever changed the day magic erupts in him. He discovers he has a powerful gift - he is a Nature Mage, able to control natural forces and creatures and bend them to his will. It is a rare gift, and no-one has been born with it in centuries, but Gaspi's powers also have a dark side, and without training they will kill him. He is forced to leave his home and travel to the distant city of Helioport, where the Archmages of the College of Collective Magicks will teach him how to use his powers. Accompanied by his guardian and his best friends, Gaspi sets off on the long journey to Helioport. The journey is fraught with danger, and Gaspi and his friends discover that there are demonic creatures abroad, intent on finding and killing anyone with magical ability. As Gaspi begins his magical studies, a shadow hangs over him and over the city of magicians. Gaspi's story of a demonic attack is not an isolated incident.As these stories increase, Hephistole, the Chancellor of the college, is growing increasingly certain that someone or something is directing the demonic forces, but who, and to what end? As things unfold, Gaspi finds himself in the middle of dark and terrible times, and can only hope that his powerful gift will develop in time to make a difference when the time comes.

The cover matches and Gaspi kind of has elemental magic. He does fight in an arena in the middle part of the book. The town where the school is, *Helioport*, does have an annual tournament and Gaspi competes in it. Finally it was published in 2011 so you could have read it seven years ago.

However while there are various girls that Gaspi is involved with there is no girl called *Marie*.